# Hide border in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker and want to remove the cell border around the days and months.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget td {
        border: 0px !important;
    }
```

I have also attached an image to show the borders that I am trying to get rid of.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You likely need to progress through the HTML tags. Do you have the site live anywhere? That way I can take a look at the CSS and put together a solution for you.

Comment: no dont have site

Comment: Use your Dev tools inspector in browser to find out where exactly that border comes from then tweak it (that is what all of us will / would do). This website is all about code, we need [mre] in order to help you, not images. Or at least find an online example of this...

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you may create a border-like effect using at least 3 properties. Not knowing more about your case, try:

```
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
outline: none;
```

Maybe with `!important`.